# Why sentDate and receivedDate are sometimes equal?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

```
val dates = emailConnector
            .emailsFrom(null, "Sent")
            .parallelStream()
            .map { it.sentDate to it.receivedDate }
            .toList()

        dates
            .map {
                when
                {
                    it.first > it.second -> "SENT"
                    it.first < it.second -> "RECEIVED"
                    it.first == it.second -> "EQUAL"
                    else -> "?"
                }
            }
            .asSequence()
            .fold(mutableMapOf<String, Int>()) { acc, s ->
                if(acc[s] == null) acc[s] = 1
                else acc[s] = acc[s]!!+1

                acc
            }
            .let { println(it) }
```

`EmailConnector.emailsFrom` returns `List<javax.mail.Message>`. The null means that I do not want to use any filter.

Output result is:

```
{SENT=44, RECEIVED=4473, EQUAL=10}
```

I have run my above code on my personal mailbox (folder "Sent" to be more precise) and I was wondering, why:

1. Messages that I have sent (and placed in my "Sent" folder do have set receivedDate? Is it a date when I have downloaded this message from "Sent" folder or is it a date when my recipient has received my message? What if there are more than one recipients? What if I am one of those recipients?
2. Most messages have receivedDate > sentDate, but not all. Why?
3. Just a few of messages have equal receivedDate and sentDate. What does it mean? Is it because the server was too quick to process this message and time interval between two actions was less than one second and therefore it looks like those two (in reality - different) dates are equal?

Unfortunately, javadoc does not describe those two dates:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html

Answer (score 1):

The sent date is set by the sender.  We hope it is accurate but it's not trustworthy.  It could be set to anything.  And in some messages it won't be set at all.

The received date is typically set when the message is added to your mailbox.  The received date is provided by your IMAP server.  POP3 servers don't provide a received date.

To answer your questions about why some of the sent and received dates are the same, I would need to see the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to see what the IMAP server is returning.  If a message is sent by another user using the same mail server, it's possible that the message could be sent and received in the same second, and thus the times could be identical.  And if there's time skew between the sender and the receiver it's possible for the times to appear to be the same.